# how to fully automate Saucelabs tests with Maven?

Tags: java, selenium, saucelabs

This is the workflow I'm trying to automate (it's a Java web app):

1. A developer creates/edits test suite(s) in Selenium IDE (w/Firefox)
2. The suite is maintained in project repository as a collection of HTML files
3. On every Maven build cycle:

   1. Jetty container is started locally at `http://localhost:12345` (random port number)
   2. [SauceConnect](http://saucelabs.com/docs/sauce-connect) starts to bridge my local host and Saucelabs grid
   3. HTML test suite(s) are executed at the grid, against my local container
   4. SauceConnect is shut down
   5. Jetty container is shut down
   6. If any test failed in the test suite - Maven build fails

Is it possible to achieve this? A more specific question is how to run HTML test suites at Saucelabs? They have a very short documentation about `http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/selenium-server/driver/`, which I can use, but I didn't find any details about it.

Answer (score 5):

I've recently created a [Sauce Connect plugin for Maven](https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/tree/master/sauce-connect-plugin), which provides Mojos to start and stop a Sauce Connect process.

This will allow you to use a combination of Cargo (which can be configured to launch Jetty), Failsafe] and Sauce Connect to instantiate your container and Sauce Connect, run your tests, and shut down the container and Sauce Connect once the tests have completed, all of which can be run by invoking `mvn verify`.

The Sauce Connect Maven plugin can be included in your project by adding the following to your pom.xml file:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <!-- Include Sauce Connect plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.saucelabs.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sauce-connect-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15</version>
        <configuration>
            <sauceUsername>YOUR_SAUCE_USERNAME</sauceUsername>
            <sauceAccessKey>YOUR_SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY</sauceAccessKey>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <!-- Start Sauce Connect prior to running the integration tests -->
            <execution>
                <id>start-sauceconnct</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start-sauceconnect</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <!-- Stop the Sauce Connect process after the integration tests have finished -->
            <execution>
                <id>stop-sauceconnect</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>stop-sauceconnect</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
</build>
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
   <id>saucelabs-repository</id>
   <url>http://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release</url>
   <releases>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I have also created a [simple example project](https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/tree/master/sauce-connect-example), which demonstrates the usage of the Sauce Connect plugin along with Cargo and Failsafe.

The plugin is fairly new, so please let me know if you have any feedback!

Comment: Looks great, thanks! Does it support parallel executions of the same build at the same server?

Comment: It *should* support parallel execution as the code is reusing the logic contained in the Sauce CI plugins, which ensures that a single Sauce Connect instance is running per Sauce user, and that Sauce Connect is only closed when the last process that invokes it is finished.  Let me know if there's any problems though:)